# Is there a way to use pypoman (or something equivalent) for getting the vertices of a linear problem involving inequalities AND also equalities?

Tags: python, linear-programming

That's basically it.

All I could find was libraries that solve the problem involving ONLY inequalities and my particular problem also shield some equalities.

Answer (score 0):

I figured the answer myself!

I can't believe i didn't realized it earlier.

Basically if you have something like:

a*x + b*y + c*z = d

that's absolutely the same as:

a*x + b*y + c*z <= d
AND
a*x + b*y + c*z >= d

and that's all inequalities :)